# pymongo, find records by date and ignore hours minutes

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have mongodb, but when populating it, collection contains in datetime.datetime objects also hours, minutes so on

How to set query to (in python3) find only by year, month and day ignoring other values?

Python3 syntax please

Comment: You need to search on a date range. Get the date component, add a day and then filter using `$gt` and `$lte` on the dates. For more help, post your attempt.

Comment: Thanks, will see how it goes